# how to round the div bottom right corner (html) in different radius then the other corners?

Tags: css, html

I want the bottom right corner to have a different radius than the other corners.How can I do that? What CSS tags I need to add to the DIV so It will look like that. *See Image

Is it possible, are there any suggestion? could you add a link with a good explantion?

Thanks for the help!

[image]

refer http://up351.siz.co.il/up1/trqzzidwwyoh.png

Comment: That's not really what you'd call a different radius. You can style each corner seperately. (border-bottom-left-radius, border-bottom-right-radius, border-top-left-radius, border-top-right-radius) Though for 'talking bubble' type effect, you can find some help here: http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are trying to create a custom shape and not really to change the radius of the corner.
Do some googling for "CSS shapes", there is a technique to manipulate the borders and the corners to create any shape using CSS.

See "Talk Bubble" on http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
Anyways, for this to work, CSS3 compliant browser is required.

JSFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/KGyUJ/7/